# Save recorded audio

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I Trying to save my recorded voice. When I press the 'save' button the recorded audio should save to a .wav file. But this is not happening. This is the code I have so far...

Record button...

```
function recordbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to recordbutton (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
rec = audiorecorder
disp('Recording for 5 Seconds...')
recordblocking (rec,5); %5 Seconds
disp('Finished Recording.')

global myrecording
myrecording = getaudiodata(rec);

axes(handles.axes3);
plot(myrecording)
```

Save button...

```
% --- Executes on button press in saverecording.
function saverecording_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global myrecording
audiowrite(myrecording, 'RecordedSound.wav');
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? does your code not work? Is it incomplete?

Comment: When I press the 'save' button the recorded audio should save to a .wav file. But this is not happening.

Comment: What *does* happen? Do you get an empty .wav file? Are you sure the callback gets called at all? Does `myrecording` contain the data you think it does at that point in time if you inspect it during debugging? Have you tried the `audiowrite` command at the debug console by itself to see if it works as intended?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a guide variable scoping issue. 
I believe best practice is to use guidata as opposed to attempting to use global variables. [mathworks Q&A here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/88518-create-a-global-variable-in-a-gui).

Secondly your audiowrite code is called in another fashion (at least on my system)
From mathworks [help here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiowrite.html), `audiowrite(filename,y,Fs)` takes a filename, the sound, and then the Frequency as inputs.

Putting all of this together, there is a bit of a change in your code but this will record a wav file with two buttons.

```
function recordbutton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
rec = audiorecorder
disp('Recording for 5 Seconds...')
recordblocking (rec,5); %5 Seconds
disp('Finished Recording.')
handles.myrecording = getaudiodata(rec);
guidata(hObject, handles); %writes the handles structure back to the guiframe.
```

Your save function should be written like this

```
function Save_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Save (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
handles.myrecording % check to make sure handles.myrecording actually has data
audiowrite('RecordedSound.wav',handles.myrecording, 44100);
```

There is no need to write the guidata back in the save, unless you want to delete the recording to free up memory.